# stuck in use of vector of structure

Tags: c++, vector

This is my code. I'm Trying to find max element in this. The Data_Test file is a simple txt file that have 12 data. In my case, 12 number that list one by one below to each other : `122 135 148 156 178 189 256 114 125 136 630 360`. compiler says that `cannot convert 'main()::str' to 'int' in initialization`. How can i convert it to `int`?

```
ifstream input("Data_Test.txt");

const int NUMstr = 4;

struct str{
string Data[NUMstr];
};

str vec;
vector<str> event;

    int maxElementIndex = max_element(event.begin(), event.end()) - event.begin();
    int maxElement = *max_element(event.begin(), event.end());

    int minElementIndex = min_element(event.begin(), event.end()) - event.begin();
    int minElement = *min_element(event.begin(), event.end());

    cout << "maxElementIndex:" << maxElementIndex << ", maxElement:" << maxElement;
    cout << "minElementIndex:" << minElementIndex << ", minElement:" << minElement;
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to `int`?

Comment: Where is the code that reads from input? On which line is the error?

Comment: So you think that the minimum element in a `vector` of `str`-s has type `int`?

Comment: why does `struct str` have an array of 4 strings?

Comment: The declaration `string Data[NUMstr];` means every `Data` element is a `string`. It might be a string of numeric characters but that is not an `int`.

Comment: Who knows. If you provide us more details about your problem, we may answer. For example, why `event[0].Data[1]` and not `event[0].Data[0]`, why you store them as `string` instead of `int`, why do you need `4` values, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first strange thing is why you are using strings when you actually have integers.

The second strange thing is why you have (effectively) a vector of arrays.

```
struct str{
    string Data[NUMstr];
};
```

This is an array wrapped inside a structure. And this `vector<str>` is a vector of structures, each of which wraps an array. I see no reason that you need this, in your problem description you just have a list of twelve numbers.

You're also a little confused about how iterators work.

So I suspect you are just getting confused and making things way more complicated than they need to be. This code works, it's a simple vector of integers, I suspect it is all that you need.

```
vector<int> event;
...
int maxElementIndex = max_element(event.begin(), event.end()) - event.begin();
int maxElement = event[maxElementIndex];
```

Comment: Hey john, Thanks for your answers but i have to use structure ! Is there any thing to do ? I mean converting this to `int` as i said ?

Comment: @AA360c Hard to say without knowing why you need to use a structure, and what benefit it's going to bring.

Comment: @AA360c I took a guess, it seems I was wrong. Unfortuneately there's way too much unsaid in your question. Why to you need a struct, why do you need an array of structs, why are you using strings, what are you trying to find the maximum and minimum of etc. etc.

Comment: @AA360c Well I'm afraid that doesn't clear anything up, it says you have a file with twelve integers but you already said that above. None of my questions in the previous comment are answered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the logic how you want your `str` struct to be converted to `int`. You can convert `std::string` to `int` using [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), e.g.:

```
const int i = std::stoi("123");
```